# How to use areas with controllers from a different assembly?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-mvc-controller

I'm starting a new ASP.NET MVC project, and I decided to put my controllers in a different assembly. Evertyhing works fine, but I have hit a problem: I created a new area in my MVC Project, called Administration. I have an AdminController Class in my seperate assembly which is supposed to return views from my Admin area, but everytime it tries to return a view,
it looks for it in the wrong place (~/Admin/SomeView.cshtml Instead of ~/Administration/Admin/SomeView.cshtml)
How can I tell the controller to look for views in the wanted area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look into [this article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/storing-asp-net-mvc-controllers-views-in-separate-assemblies.aspx). And also you problem was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910089/how-to-separate-model-view-and-controller-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app-into-different-a).

Basically you will need to extend MvcViewEngine, to tell MVC to look for your Views in the different from standatd pathes:

```
public class YourMegaViewEngine : WebFormViewEngine
{
    public YourMegaViewEngine ()
    {
        ViewLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
            "~/Views/Administration/{1}/{0}.cshtml" //I may be wrong for you case, but this is the place to puth you path
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not my problem... The controller (or ViewEngine...) can find my views, unless they are in an area. Your suggested solution won't help in my case, but thx anyway :)

Comment: Why not, have you looked at the first article? Areas is just another folders above views, you can solve this problem going the same way.