# Model, controller or view to the other class library

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, class-library

How can I separate Model and Controller to the other class library because in large project the number of views/model/controller might increase to "N" number which becomes difficult for me to traverse the correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910089/how-to-separate-model-view-and-controller-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app-into-different-a) help you? (It's referenced on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910089/how-to-separate-model-view-and-controller-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app-into-different-a))